# Can I select several tables in the same WITH query?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a long query with a `with` structure. At the end of it, I'd like to output two tables. Is this possible?

(The tables and queries are in snowflake SQL by the way.)

The code looks like this:

```
with table_a as (
               select id, 
                      product_a
               from x.x ),
     table_b as (
               select id, 
                      product_b
               from x.y ),
     table_c as ( 

..... many more alias tables and subqueries here .....

             )

select * from table_g where z = 3 ;
```

But for the very last row, I'd like to query table_g twice, once with z = 3 and once with another condition, so I get two tables as the result. Is there a way of doing that (ending with two queries rather than just one) or do I have to re-run the whole code for each table I want as output?

Comment: What do you mean "two tables in the result"?  A single query returns a single result set.

Comment: Ah, right, guess that's the answer to that question. Thanks for letting me know! @JNevill

Comment: @JNevill post your comment as a reply and I'll close this question. That's really all I wanted to know, thank you very much for your detailed response :)

Comment: I cleaned up my comment and brought through your sql (with some edits) to explain the CTE/Non-CTE sameness that I assume was leading to the hope that you could get two result sets out of this. You could consider temporary tables to materialize your CTEs so you can query twice (assuming the logic in the CTEs is complex enough to warrant materializing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One query = One result set. That's just the way that RDBMS's work.

A CTE (`WITH` statement) is just syntactic sugar for a subquery.

For instance, a query similar to yours:

```
with table_a as (
               select id, 
                      product_a
               from x.x ),
     table_b as (
               select id, 
                      product_b
               from x.y ),
     table_c as (     
               select id, 
                      product_c
               from x.z ),

select * 
from table_a
   inner join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.id
   inner join table_c on table_b.id = table_c.id;
```

Is 100% identical to:

```
select *
from
  (select id, product_a from x.x) table_a
  inner join (select id, product_b from x.y) table_b
      on table_a.id = table_b.id
  inner join (select id, product_c from x.z) table_c
      on table_b.id = table_c.id
```

The CTE version doesn't give you any extra features that aren't available in the non-cte version (with the exception of a recursive cte) and the execution path will be 100% the same (EDIT: Please see Simon's answer and comment below where he notes that Snowflake may materialize the derived table defined by the CTE so that it only has to perform that step once should the CTE be referenced multiple times in the main query). As such there is still no way to get a second result set from the single query.

Comment: CTE's should only execute that section/part a single time, so if you join to the CTE multiple times, the CTE stage should only happen once, which is of value if that part is very expensive. For some really large reports we found the performance plan shows this was happening in snowflake..

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim That's good to hear that snowflake has the sense to reuse a materialized derived table like that from the CTE definition. I've found it frustrating when, in other products, it's treated as a subquery from an execution standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

While they are the same syntactically, they don't have the same performance plan.

The first case can be when one of the stages in the CTE is expensive, and is reused via other CTE's or join to many times, under Snowflake, use them as a CTE I have witness it running the "expensive" part only a single time, which can be good so for example like this.

```
WITH expensive_select AS (
    SELECT a.a, b.b, c.c
    FROM table_a AS a
    JOIN table_b AS b
    JOIN table_c AS c
    WHERE complex_filters
), do_some_thing_with_results AS (
    SELECT stuff
    FROM expensive_select
    WHERE filters_1
), do_some_agregation AS (
    SELECT a, SUM(b) as sum_b
    FROM expensive_select
    WHERE filters_2
)
SELECT a.a
    ,a.b
    ,b.stuff
    ,c.sum_b
FROM expensive_select AS a
LEFT JOIN do_some_thing_with_results AS b ON a.a = b.a
LEFT JOIN do_some_agregation AS c ON a.a = b.a;
```

This was originally unrolled, and the expensive part was some VIEWS that the date range filter that was applied at the top level were not getting pushed down (due to window functions) so resulted in full table scans, multiple times. Where pushing them into the CTE the cost was paid once. (In our case putting date range filters in the CTE made Snowflake notice the filters and push them down into the view, and things can change, a few weeks later the original code ran as good as the modified, so they "fixed" something)

In other cases, like this the different paths that used the CTE use smaller sub-sets of the results, so using the CTE reduced the remote IO so improved performance, there then was more stalls in the execution plan.

I also use CTEs like this to make the code easier to read, but giving the CTE a meaningful name, but the aliasing it to something short, for use. Really love that.